# How do i print separate digits from a 3 digit php variable?

Tags: php, variables

Like I am attempting to use data by using SQL query.
After that, the **PHP** variable contain **123**.
Now I want to print **1, 2** and **3** separately on html page.

Comment: what do you mean by *separately on html page*?

Answer (score 0):

A string is basically an array of characters, so you can access each char by position easily. You will need to make sure that your value is a string - if it is a number you need to [cast it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

```
<?php
$value = 123;

// Cast our value to a string
$stringValue = (string) $value;

$firstChar = $stringValue[0];
$secondChar = $stringValue[1];
$thirdChar = $stringValue[2];
echo $firstChar.PHP_EOL;
echo $secondChar.PHP_EOL;
echo $thirdChar.PHP_EOL;
```